# Undefined reference to gl functions when using QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, linker, qglwidget

I'm trying to port my old Qt/OpenGL game from Linux to Windows.
I'm using Qt Creator.
It compiled fine right away but gave a lot of errors like `undefined reference to 'glUniform4fv@12'` at linking stage.

I've tried to link more libs `-lopengl32 -lglaux -lGLU32 -lglut -lglew32` but it gave the same result.

Qt also uses `-lQt5OpenGLd` by default.

I'm including QGLWIdget with :

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <QGLWidget>
```

I've also tried using GLEW but it confilcts with Qt (or QOpenGL?).

How can I get rid of those undefined references?
Is there any other library that i have to link to?

Thanks in advance.

Tomxey

Comment: Windows just does not export anything beyond GL1.1 in its opengl32.dll. The `#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` you did was a hack which was not even guaranteed to work on Linux, but it is never going to work on windows. You'll need to query the function pointers at runtime, either manually or via some helper library like glew. However, I don't know enough about Qt and it's GL widget to provide a real answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows doesn't provide the prototypes of any OpenGL function introduced after OpenGL 1.1. **You must resolve the pointers to those functions at runtime** (via `GetProcAddress` -- or better `QOpenGLContext::getProcAddress`, see below).

---

Qt offers excellent enablers to ease this job:

- `QOpenGLShader` and `QOpenGLShaderProgram` allow you manage your shaders, shader programs, and their uniforms. QOpenGLShaderProgram provides nice overloads allowing you to seamlessly pass `QVector<N>D` or `QMatrix<N>x<N>` classes:

  ```
  QMatrix4x4 modelMatrix = model->transform();
  QMatrix4x4 modelViewMatrix = camera->viewMatrix() * modelMatrix;
  QMatrix4x4 modelViewProjMatrix = camera->projMatrix() * modelViewMatrix;
  ...
  program->setUniform("mv", modelViewmatrix);
  program->setUniform("mvp", modelViewProjMatrix);
  ```
- `QOpenGLContext::getProcAddress()` is a platform-independent function resolver (useful in combination with `QOpenGLContext::hasExtension()` to load extension-specific functions)
- `QOpenGLContext::functions()` returns a [QOpenGLFunctions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglfunctions.html) object (owned by the context), which offers as public API the common subset between OpenGL 2 (+FBO) / OpenGL ES 2.¹ It will resolve the pointers behind the scenes for you, so all you have to do is calling

  ```
  functions->glUniform4f(...);
  ```
- `QOpenGLContext::versionFunctions<VERSION>()` will return a `QAbstractOpenGLFunctions` subclass, namely, the one matching the `VERSION` template parameter (or NULL if the request can't be satisfied):

  ```
  QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core *functions = 0;
  functions = context->versionFunctions<QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core>();
  if (!functions) 
       error(); // context doesn't support the requested version+profile
  functions->initializeOpenGLFunctions(context);

  functions->glSamplerParameterf(...); // OpenGL 3.3 API
  functions->glPatchParameteri(...); // COMPILE TIME ERROR, this is OpenGL 4.0 API
  ```
- As an alternative way, you can make your "drawing" classes /inherit/ from `QOpenGLFunctionsX`. You can initalize them as usual, but this way you can keep your code like:

  ```
  class DrawThings : public QObject, protected QOpenGLFunctions_2_1
  {
      explicit DrawThings(QObject *parent = 0) { ... }
      bool initialize(QOpenGLContext *context)
      {
          return initializeOpenGLFunctions(context);
      }
      void draw()
      {
          Q_ASSERT(isInitialized());
          // works, it's calling the one in the QOpenGLFunctions_2_1 scope...
          glUniform4f(...); 
      }
  }
  ```

---

¹ There are also "matching" classes in the `QtOpenGL` module, i.e. `QGLContext` and `QGLFunctions`. If possible, avoid using `QtOpenGL` in new code, as it's going to be deprecated in a couple of releases in favour of the `QOpenGL*` classes.